# Problem in rbind(), Cannot output with same row numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

```
time3a=time3[-(1:8),]
```

time3a is a data frame with 60 rows before I do the operation above.After I deleted 8 rows.When I was trying to combine it with another 52 rows data frame a using rbind. An error occurs like this

```
rbind(time3a,a)
```

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments
>   do not match

Here is the output of my time3a dataframe.It may cause the problem because of rownames. As for the new dataframe is pure number and no modification has been applied. I don't know how to solve it, any suggestions?

```
    time1 time2
    <int> <int>
9   2012    9       
10  2012    10      
11  2012    11      
12  2012    12      
13  2013    1       
14  2013    2       
15  2013    3       
16  2013    4       
17  2013    5       
18  2013    6
```

dataframe a

```
  a
<dbl>
1.71                
1.90                
2.74                
4.20                
1.45                
1.80                
2.03                
1.99                
2.32                
2.20
```

Comment: Based on the data and code provided, it's impossible to know what you're doing. Please provide code and snippets of data in as reproducible manner as possible to get the best and fastest answer.

Comment: I think this is easier to understand now

Comment: You can't `rbind` two data frames unless they have the same column names. Did you perhaps want to `cbind`?

Comment: @Edward No, I simply want to add the dataframe a as a new column to dataframe time3a. Anyway I can do it?

Comment: Then `cbind` will do that !  Or `data.frame()`. Or simply `time3$a <- a$a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work based on what you said
 `time3a$a<-a`

Answer (score 0):

If both dataframes have the same length, adding a new column with `time3a$a <- a$a` may work.